Selenium test build fails on Jenkins
I created Jenkins job and trying to launch a selenium test(java), but the build keeps failing with the following error. Both, Jenkins primary and agent machines are on AWS. Everything works perfectly on local machine, but fails on the agent machine. It looks like testng version defined in gradle build file is not compatible with Java version that is being used on the agent machine. Checked Java version on agent and it is correct one.
Is it because the path to Java needs to be indicated somewhere in Gradle properties file or in Jenkins configuration?
> > Task :compileJava FAILED
> 
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
> 
> * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
>    > Could not resolve org.testng:testng:7.7.1.
>      Required by:
>          project :
>       > No matching variant of org.testng:testng:7.7.1 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during compile-time,
> compatible with Java 9, preferably in the form of class files,
> preferably optimized for standard JVMs, and its dependencies declared
> externally but:
>           - Variant 'antApiElements' capability org.testng:testng-ant:7.7.1 declares a library for use during
> compile-time, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared
> externally:
>               - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a
> component, compatible with Java 9
>               - Other compatible attribute:
>                   - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for standard JVMs)
>           - Variant 'antRuntimeElements' capability org.testng:testng-ant:7.7.1 declares a library for use during runtime,
> packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
>               - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a
> component, compatible with Java 9
>               - Other compatible attribute:
>                   - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for standard JVMs)
      

Added this line into gradle-wrapper.properties: org.gradle.java.home=/home/jenkins/jdk
Added properties file in Jenkins configuration with Java home path, however nothing from the above has helped.

As per the logs, you are using java 9, but the testng version you want to use(7.7.1) requires java 11. you should either update your jdk version to 11 or should downgrade testng version. Please confirm which Java version is being used in Jenkins slave.

I was thinking the same way until I checked JDK version on both, slave and master. Both appeared to be using JDK-17. That is what makes me completely lost.

Can you check the java version in the jenkins job itself, run java version command just before gradle command to check maybe the job is picking some other java present on the slave. and if it is not JDK17, check which java is being used in jenkins job by which java

@RahulSharma thanks for the tip. So I ran two commands suggested by you and got this:
`+ java -version
java version "9.0.4"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.4+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.4+11, mixed mode)

which java
/home/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/JDK-17/bin/java`


Adding this as answer, cause it's gonna be a long comment.
Did you run which java in the jenkins job same as the version command? 
cause these are two different results, java 9 can't be in folder of JDK-17.
Anyways, you can try these two commands after installing java 11, cause I think java 17 will result in a new error, in jenkins job just before gradle command in the same shell session (assuming you slave is unix/linux/mac):
export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java11
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME:$PATH
<your gradle command here>


Thanks Rahul, these two commands fixed the issue for me: 'export JAVA_HOME=/home/jenkins/jdk and org.gradle.java.home=/home/jenkins/jdk'
